# Two different variance formulas?

Tags: probability, variance

Here's the general formula for variance:

$$Var(X) = E[(X - E[X])^2]$$

We can algebraically manipulate this
$$E[(X - E[X])^2] = E[(X - E[X])(X - E[X])]$$
$$= E[X^2 - 2XE[X] + E[X]^2]$$
$$= E[X^2] - 2E[X]E[X] + E[X]^2$$
$$= E[X^2] - E[X]^2$$

So $Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$

My question is could we also use $E[X(X - E[X])]$ to express variance? If so, why?

$$E[X(X - E[X])] = E[X^2 - XE[X]]$$
$$ = E[X^2] - E[X]E[X]$$
$$ = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$$
$$ = Var(X)$$

It seems odd that $E[(X - E[X])(X - E[X])] = E[X(X - E[X])]$ since one of the $X$'s is centered around zero while the other isn't. Can someone please explain this discrepancy to me?

Comment: $$ E\bigg(E(X) \big (X- E(X) \big ) \bigg) = E(X)E \big(X-E(X)\big)=0 $$

Comment: More generally, for any $a\in \mathbb R$,
$$
\text{Var }X=E\Big[(X-a)(X-E[X])\Big].
$$

Comment: @MikeEarnest Why does that make sense intuitively? It's generally the case that (x + 1) (x - c) is not equal to, say, (x + 9999999) (x - c). Is it the expectation function?

Comment: It is the expectation. Of course $(x+1)(x-c)$ isn't equal to $(x+99999)(x-c)$ *as random variables*, but the difference of their expectations is equal to $99998 \mathbb E[x-c]$, which is equal to $0$ if $c = \mathbb E[x]$. In other words, we just saw two random variables $Y,Z$ which "look very different" but for which $\mathbb E[Y] = \mathbb E[Z]$. There's nothing that should be awesome about that.